# Shift complex numpy array by 0.25 or 0.5 samples

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

I want to shift my complex signal by half and by a quarter sample.
Is there any fundamental difference between performing this shift with a FFT (frequency ramp in frequency domain) or shifting with a cubic or spline interpolation? (except for computational burden)
What is the more accurate approach?

Thanks

Comment: This question is probably better asked at https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: https://dsp.stackexchange.com will probably get you a better answer than here